# Skip subdirectories when using ntfw in c

Tags: c, linux, filetree, nftw

I am trying to get all the files and directories in the current or mentioned folder using [nftw](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw). But how do I instruct the function not to go further in any subdirectory? What is the purpose of the flag `FTW_SKIP_SUBTREE`? Also what is the header file for this constant.

```
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static int
display_info(const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
             int tflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{

    printf("%-3s %2d %7jd   %-40s %d %s\n",
        (tflag == FTW_D) ?   "d"   : (tflag == FTW_DNR) ? "dnr" :
        (tflag == FTW_DP) ?  "dp"  : (tflag == FTW_F) ?   "f" :
        (tflag == FTW_NS) ?  "ns"  : (tflag == FTW_SL) ?  "sl" :
        (tflag == FTW_SLN) ? "sln" : "???",
        ftwbuf->level, (intmax_t) sb->st_size,
        fpath, ftwbuf->base, fpath + ftwbuf->base);
    return 0;           /* To tell nftw() to continue */
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flags = 0;

    if (argc > 2 && strchr(argv[2], 'd') != NULL)
      flags |= FTW_DEPTH;
    if (argc > 2 && strchr(argv[2], 'p') != NULL)
      flags |= FTW_PHYS;
    if (argc > 2 && strchr(argv[2], 's') != NULL)
      flags |= FTW_SKIP_SUBTREE;

    if (nftw((argc < 2) ? "." : argv[1], display_info, 20, flags)
            == -1) {
        perror("nftw");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I try to compile I get this message

```
test.c:33:16: error: ‘FTW_SKIP_SUBTREE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       flags |= FTW_SKIP_SUBTREE;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual page for `nftw()` on Linux says (in part):

> `nftw()`
>
> The function `nftw()` is the same as `ftw()`, except that it has one additional argument, `flags`,
>          and calls `fn()` with one more argument, `ftwbuf`.
>
> This flags argument is formed by ORing zero or more of the following flags:
>
> - `FTW_ACTIONRETVAL` (since glibc 2.3.3)
>     If  this  glibc-specific  `flag` is set, then `nftw()` handles the return value from `fn()`
>               differently.  `fn()` should return one of the following values:
>
>   - `FTW_CONTINUE`
>                    Instructs `nftw()` to continue normally.
>   - `FTW_SKIP_SIBLINGS`
>                    If `fn()` returns this value,  then  siblings  of  the  current  entry  will  be
>                    skipped, and processing continues in the parent.
>   - `FTW_SKIP_SUBTREE`
>                    If  `fn()` is called with an entry that is a directory (`typeflag` is `FTW_D`), this
>                    return value will prevent objects within that directory from being  passed  as
>                    arguments  to  `fn()`.  `nftw()` continues processing with the next sibling of the
>                    directory.
>   - `FTW_STOP`
>                    Causes `nftw()` to return immediately with the return value FTW_STOP.
>   - Other return values could be associated with new actions in the future;  `fn()`  should
>             not return values other than those listed above.
>
>   The  feature test macro `_GNU_SOURCE` must be defined in order to obtain the definition
>               of `FTW_ACTIONRETVAL` from `<ftw.h>`.

The last paragraph is the crucial one for you to note.